# Are the results of `IncrementalValueProvider` extensions cached and compared?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, csharp-source-generator

`SyntaxValueProvider.CreateSyntaxProvider` takes two `Func` arguments: a *predicate* that filters the syntax elements, and a *transform* that returns the interesting details from the syntax context. The result sets from each `Func` are cached and compared with previous invocations to avoid unnecessary regeneration.

`CreateSyntaxProvider` returns an `IncrementalValuesProvider`, which has several extension methods that look like LINQ but aren't. **Are the result sets from these extensions also cached and compared, potentially preventing regeneration if their output is unchanged?**

In many tutorials, the transform returns either the interesting details from the syntax context, or null. The nulls are then removed with a pseudo-LINQ `Where`:

```
var provider = context.SyntaxProvider.CreateSyntaxProvider(
        (syntax, _) => Predicate(syntax), 
        (syntaxContext, _) => DetailsOrNull(syntaxContext))
    .Where(details => details != null);
initContext.RegisterSourceOutput(provider, (spc, details) => Generate(spc, details));
```

What I'm getting at with this question is whether the following would be equivalent in terms of preventing `Generate` from being called:

```
var provider = context.SyntaxProvider.CreateSyntaxProvider(
        (syntax, _) => Predicate(syntax), 
        (syntaxContext, _) => syntaxContext
    .Where(syntaxContext => IsInteresting(syntaxContext))
    .Select((syntaxContext, _) => Details(syntaxContext));
initContext.RegisterSourceOutput(provider, (spc, details) => Generate(spc, details));
```

This would be less efficient if `IsInteresting` and `Details` extract the same information from `syntaxContext`. But if they don't duplicate work, is there any reason to do it the first way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the whole thing is a pipeline with several steps. Each step of the pipeline represents a stage which has input/output cached. I don't think that the clarify that, however Andrew Lock's [blog post](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-9-source-generator-updates-incremental-generators/) describes that well. The LINQ-like extension method `.Where` is step 4.

> It's important to understand the pipeline we've defined so far:
>
> 1. Start with all the syntax in the program
> 2. Quickly restrict to only methods that have an attribute
> 3. Transform each syntax to either the parent class, if the method has the `[LoggerMessage]` attribute, or return null.
> 4. Filter out null values.
>
> Stages 2-4 will run a lot, basically for every edit you make in your
> IDE. But unless you're actually adding something that will change
> generation, i.e. a method with the `[LoggerMessage]` attribute, **the
> output of step 4 will remain constant. That means nothing else in your
> generator needs to execute. This is a really powerful point, as it can
> massively reduce the amount of work that needs to happen.**

Also image from the blog post:

[image]